# What do these Option Alerts mean?

Tags: call-options, alerts

What do these **Option Alert**s mean?

- **Uber Technologies Option Alert: Jan 17 $31 Calls Sweep (19) near the Ask: 1000 @ $0.6 vs 5648 OI; Earnings 2/4 Before Open [est] Ref=$28.695**
- **Slack Technologies Option Alert: Fri $21 Calls Sweep (41) near the Ask: 543 @ $0.5 vs 155 OI; Ref=$21.11**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a  [Sweep Order](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sweeptofillorder.asp) to buy 19 Jan 17 $31 calls on Uber near the ask price of 60 cents.

The Open Interest for this contract is 5,648 contracts

$28.695 is the stock’s price